# Simulate request in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, http, jquery, cookies

I have a Jquery Ajax request which goes to Facebook server. (jsonP)

However , Im not satisfy with the current response and I would like to "edit" the response *before* it goes back to the ajax call.

In order to do it , I was thinking about building a `proxy` by ashx. ( it will do the request , and when the response is back - he will edit it , and it will return to the ajax call).

```
jQuery ajax ---> myHandler.ashx ----> Facebook +--->
                                                    |
                                                    |
jQuery ajax <---- myHandler.ashx(+edit) <-----------+
```

the problem is that Facebook requires its cookies , And IMHO -only facebook can access its cookies.

Is there any way for the ashx handler to be able to TRANSFER the cookie along with his request ( as if jQuery ajax would do ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you may simulate a cookie-aware user agent and relay them to user.

**Request 1:**

- Browser sends the first request to your ashx handler.
- Your handler relays it to facebook server.
- FB responds with a content + a set-cookie header(s) (**fb-cookie=xxx** on **facebook.com**)
- Your handler edits the content and returns the set-cookie header with some kind of prefix (**your-fb-cookie=xxx** on **yoursite.com**)

**Request 2:**

- Next time the browser sends a request to your ashx handler, you will receive the the "**your-fb-cookie=xxx**" (as it is defined on **yoursite.com**)
- Your handler relays the request to FB with the cookie "**fb-cookie=xxx**"
- ...

**However,** be aware that facebook (or any other service) may (and should) use some kind of anti-flood detection.
It may block your server's IP adress as it receives lots of requests from it.
This can even be against FB licensing terms.